# Form validation issue in macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3

I am trying to run through a settings form and make sure that the user hasn't left any of the required fields empty.

Some of the forms fields are secure ( eg password).

Whats the easiest way to loop through all these fields and check they are not empty?

I have tried below - but I get a weird error:

```
if textfield1.stringValue == "", 
    textfield2.stringValue == "",
    passwordfield.stringValue == "" {
        //Shows error: Braced block of statements is an unused closure
}
```

Additionally I am unable to group all these NSTextfields into an array as the password textfields are NSSecureTextField which despite being inherited from NSTextfield, the are not groupable with NSTextfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* have `NSTextField` and `NSSecureTextField` in the same array. This is indeed an easy way to find the empty ones.

```
let tf = NSTextField()
let stf = NSSecureTextField()
let tf2 = NSTextField()
tf2.stringValue = "some text"

let all = [tf, stf, tf2]

let emptyTextFields = all.filter { $0.stringValue.isEmpty }
```

Also in your example you can't use commas to group conditions in `if`, you have to use `&&`:

```
if tf.stringValue.isEmpty && stf.stringValue.isEmpty && tf2.stringValue.isEmpty {
    // do something
}
```

but this is not a good solution, better use the array and filter.

Answer (score 0):

Under Swift 2, here's what Eric Aya correctly identified:

```
    if textfield1.stringValue == "" && textfield2.stringValue == "" &&  == "" {

    }
```

It also compiles under Swift 3.

On the other hand, the code you put in your question actually works in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to check empty string with *isEmpty* variable of String object.

```
let userName = ""
let email = ""

if(userName.isEmpty && email.isEmpty) {
    print("empty strings")
}
else {
    print("good strings")
}
```